# How to solve Dapper - UnitOfWork Transaction Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, unit-of-work

I'm trying to implement unit of work repository pattern with Dapper in ASP.NET Core Web API.

I have created the model,repository and UOW. When I try to do GET request I got an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: BeginExecuteReader requires the
> command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the
> command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property
> of the command has not been initialized.

Here is my controller;

```
 public class CityController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        public CityController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<City>> GetAll()
        {
            return await unitOfWork.Cities.All();
        }
```

CityRepository.cs

```
internal class CityRepository : GenericRepository<City>, ICityRepository
    {
       public CityRepository(IDbTransaction transaction)
            : base(transaction)
        {

        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<City>> All()
        {

            var model = await Connection.QueryAsync<City>("SELECT * FROM DT_Inspection.City");
            return model.ToList();

        }
}
```

```
public IConfiguration configuration;
        private IDbTransaction _transaction;
        private IDbConnection _connection;
        ICityRepository _cityRepository;
        private bool _disposed;

        public UnitOfWork(IConfiguration _configuration)
        {
            configuration = _configuration;
            _connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            _connection.Open();
            _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();          
        }
        public ICityRepository Cities { get { return _cityRepository ?? (_cityRepository = new CityRepository(_transaction)); }
public void Commit()
        {
            try
            {
                _transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                _transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                _transaction.Dispose();
                _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
                resetRepositories();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to write *correct* ADO.NET code before trying to use a "repository". As the error says, you need to explicitly link a DbCommand with a transaction. Or you can use a TransactionScope. Dapper is a *very* thin mapping layer on top of ADO.NET. You still need to know how to use ADO.NET. BTW what you try to create is actually a Data Access Object, using pessimistic (ie not very scalable) concurrency. Not a real Repository that makes persistence look like in-memory operations.

Comment: What you try to do explicitly prevents the far more scalable (100-1000x) optimistic concurrency supported by ADO.NET, either through DataTables or EF's DbContext. You *will* get into deadlocks if you use explicit transactions, so you need to be prepared for them. The *easy* way to use transactions (whether you wrap them in a UoW or not) is to create a [TransactionScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=net-5.0) before opening the connection. The new connection will automatically be enlisted in the transaction

Comment: Otherwise you need to pass the database transaction to each command. In Dapper's case, this means passing it as the `transaction` parameter of `Query` or `Execute`. `Dapper` doesn't bypass ADO.NET, it creates and caches `DbCommand` instances for the SQL strings you pass to it. Needless to say, the "Repository" implementation is starting to leak, as the `CityRepository` class needs access to the `_transaction` field stored in the `UoW`

Comment: BTW the UoW **must** be disposable and it **must** dispose the connection and transaction it holds. Both should be *short-live*. That `_transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();` **violates the Unit-of-Work** pattern. Instead of representing a Unit-of-Work, what you have is a leaked long-lasting connection using implicit transactions, the way Oracle or SQL Servers do if you use specific connection string settings. Very few people use them though, because they make deadlocks and blocking a lot worse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, that's the exact opposite of a Unit-of-Work. Unit of work means you have a single, indivisible bunch ( a *unit*) of operations  (*work*) that needs to be committed or discarded as one. Once it completes, it's gone and can't be reused. That's a feature.

A UoW typically implies that the work doesn't affect the data source until it's committed, but your code starts an expensive long-lived transaction that *does* lock records from the very first read.

The class you use though creates a *global* long-lived connection and a global, implicit transaction. That's a very bad practice. These lines specificially, are a major bug :

```
_transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
resetRepositories();
```

You could achieve the same effect in any database through some connection settings but *very* few people do this.

Database connections and transactions are meant to be *short*-lived. Otherwise they accumulate locks and tie up resources on the server, causing blocking or even deadlocks between different transactions. Otherwise you could run into deadlocks or long delays even with a couple of concurrent clients. This was a huge problem in the 1990s before disconnected operations and optimistic concurrency were introduced. What you try to do puts you back in the 1990s.

The difference really is 1000x worse performance, and having to use 10x+ more database server*s* to handle the same amount of traffic.

That's why the docs, courses and tutorial (the good ones) all show connections and transactions created right before they're used :

```
using(var cn=new SqlConnection(...))
{
    cn.Open();
    using(var tx=cn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (var cmd1=new SqlCommand(sql1,cn,tx))
        {
        ...
        }
        using (var cmd2=new SqlCommand(sql2,cn,tx))
        {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you use an explicit database transaction, you *must* pass the active transaction to the command itself. That's what the exception you got says. The alternative is to use a `TransactionScope` and create open connections *inside* it. In this case, the connection is implicitly enrolled in the transaction :

```
using(var cn=new SqlConnection(...))
{
    using(var scope=new TransactionScope())
    {
        cn.Open();

        using (var cmd=new SqlCommand(sql,cn))
        {
        ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

`Dapper` is a thin mapper over ADO.NET, it doesn't replace it. This means you still have to use ADO.NET, connections and transactions correctly. If you want to use to use explicit transactions, you need to pass it through the `transaction` parameter to `Query` or `Execute`:

```
using(var cn=new SqlConnection(...))
{
    cn.Open();
    using(var tx=cn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var results1=cn.QueryAsync<City>(sql1,transaction:tx);
        
        var results2=cn.QueryAsync<City>(sql2,transaction:tx);
        
    }
}
```

Or you can use a `TransactionScope` :

```
using(var scope=new TransactionScope())
{
    using(var cn=new SqlConnection(...))
    {        
        cn.Open();
        var results1=cn.QueryAsync<City>(sql1);
        
        var results2=cn.QueryAsync<City>(sql2);        
    }
}
```

The implementation leaks already.  "Repository" (it's actually a [Data Access Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object), not a Repository) would need access to the `_transaction` field's value. Or you could use a `TransactionScope` and forget about that `UoW`. After all, access to the database is the *DAO/Repository's* job, not the UoW's. *Maybe* you could use the `UoW` as a thin wrapper over a `TransactionScope`, or have the `Repository` create and initialize the `UoW` with an explicit transaction from the connection it owns.

Assuming you use a `TransactionScope`, your UoW should be nothing more than a wrapper:

```
class UnitOfWork:IDisposable
{
    TransactionScope _scope=new TransactionScope();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _scope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The "repository" shouldn't even know about the UoW. It *should* control connections though:

```
internal class CityRepository 
{
   string _connString;
   public CityRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
        _connString=configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
   }
        
   public async Task<IEnumerable<City>> All()
   {
       using(var cn=new SqlConnection(_connStr))
       {
           var model = await Connection.QueryAsync<City>("SELECT * FROM DT_Inspection.City");
           return model.ToList();
       }
   }
}
```

Only the controller would need to create the UoW, and then, only if there's any chance of modifying data. Reads don't need transactions :

```
public class CityController : ControllerBase
{
    private ICityRepository _cityRepo;
    public CityController(ICityRepository cityRepo)
    {
        _cityRepo=cityRepo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public Task<IEnumerable<City>> GetAll()
    {
       return _cityRepo.All();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post(City[] cities)
    {
        using(var uow=new UnitOfWork())
        {
            foreach(var city in cities)
            {
                _cityRepo.Insert(city);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your informative comment. It helped me a lot.